# /sbin/dump: "Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem"

Tags: centos7, dump

I'm attempting a backup of one of our servers:

```
[root@butler /]# /sbin/dump -0uan -f - / | gzip -2 | ssh -c blowfish IRUser@192.168.0.225 dd of=/RAIDPOOL01/sysbackup/full-backup-`date '+%d-%B-%Y'`.dump.gz
```

This gives me a strange error:

```
DUMP: No group entry for operator.
DUMP: Date of this level 0 dump: Mon Feb 15 10:34:30 2016
DUMP: Dumping /dev/mapper/centos_butler-root (/) to standard output
/dev/mapper/centos_butler-root: Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem
DUMP: The ENTIRE dump is aborted.
```

What is this, and how can fix this in order to create a backup?

Output of `mount`:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=3894872k,nr_inodes=973718,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/centos_butler-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/500/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=500,group_id=500)
/etc/auto.misc on /misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=4069,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)
-hosts on /net type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=12,pgrp=4069,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)
/etc/jabba.nfs on /192.168.0.225 type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=18,pgrp=4069,timeout=120,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)
/etc/mothership.nfs on /192.168.0.226 type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=24,pgrp=4069,timeout=120,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)
```

Output of `file -L -s /dev/mapper/centos_butler-root`:

```
/dev/mapper/centos_butler-root: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 256, v2 dirs)
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `mount` and `file -L -s /dev/mapper/centos_butler-root` ?

Comment: @shodanshok yes, I added it.

Answer (score 2):

`dump` cannot dump XFS, use `xfsdump`

Answer (score 2):

To dump an XFS filesystem, you should use the `xfsdump` utility. For example:

`xfsdump -l 0 - /`

will dump the `/` filesystem to `stdout`

To dump on using another device/file as destination:

`xfsdump -l 0 -f /dev/otherdev /`

For more information, you can see [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/xfsbackuprestore.html)